# Erro ao compilar uma static library do zlib para Android

Tags: compilação, android-ndk, zlib

Tenho o arquivo de configuração Android.mk para a compilação do [zlib para Android](https://github.com/android/platform_external_zlib), mas ele contem as opções de compilação, *shared*, *static* e *host*, preciso apenas compilar uma library static, `BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY`.

Não sei o que manter ou remover do Android.mk, como eu poderia compilar corretamente removendo as opções desnecessárias?

Arquivo Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

# measurements show that the ARM version of ZLib is about x1.17 faster
# than the thumb one...
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm

zlib_files := \
    src/adler32.c \
    src/compress.c \
    src/crc32.c \
    src/deflate.c \
    src/gzclose.c \
    src/gzlib.c \
    src/gzread.c \
    src/gzwrite.c \
    src/infback.c \
    src/inflate.c \
    src/inftrees.c \
    src/inffast.c \
    src/trees.c \
    src/uncompr.c \
    src/zutil.c

LOCAL_MODULE := libz
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -O3 -DUSE_MMAP

# TODO: This is to work around b/24465209. Remove after root cause is fixed
LOCAL_LDFLAGS_arm := -Wl,--hash-style=both

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(zlib_files)
ifneq ($(TARGET_BUILD_APPS),)
  LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := 9
else
  LOCAL_CXX_STL := none
endif
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDE_DIRS := $(LOCAL_PATH)
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
LOCAL_MODULE := libz
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -O3 -DUSE_MMAP
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(zlib_files)
ifneq ($(TARGET_BUILD_APPS),)
  LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := 9
else
  LOCAL_CXX_STL := none
endif
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDE_DIRS := $(LOCAL_PATH)
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := libz
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -O3 -DUSE_MMAP
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(zlib_files)
LOCAL_MULTILIB := both
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDE_DIRS := $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_MODULE_HOST_OS := darwin linux windows
LOCAL_CXX_STL := none
include $(BUILD_HOST_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := libz-host
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -O3 -DUSE_MMAP
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(zlib_files)
LOCAL_MULTILIB := both
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDE_DIRS := $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_CXX_STL := none
include $(BUILD_HOST_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES:=        \
    src/test/minigzip.c

LOCAL_MODULE:= gzip

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libz

LOCAL_CXX_STL := none

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES:=        \
    src/test/minigzip.c

LOCAL_MODULE:= minigzip

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libz

LOCAL_CXX_STL := none

include $(BUILD_HOST_EXECUTABLE)

$(TARGET_OUT_COMMON_GEN)/zlib_fingerprint : $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/*.[ch])
    printf '%s\n' $^ | LC_ALL=C sort | xargs cat | shasum -a 256 | \
        awk '{printf $$1}' > $@
```

Ao tentar compilar com o comando `ndk-build` recebo o seguinte erro:

> [root@localhost platform_external_zlib-master]#
>   /run/media/root/linux/workspace/android-ndk-r11c/ndk-build
>   TARGET_PLATFORM=android-14 TARGET_ARCH_ABI=x86 NDK_PROJECT_PATH=.
>   Android NDK: Trying to define local module 'z' in
>   /run/media/root/Volume/platform_external_zlib-master/Android.mk.
>   Android NDK: But this module was already defined by
>   /run/media/root/Volume/platform_external_zlib-master/Android.mk.
>   /run/media/root/Volume/android-ndk-r11c/build/core/build-module.mk:34:
>   *** Android NDK: Aborting.    .  Stop. 
> [root@localhost platform_external_zlib-master]#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente o que foi preciso fazer foi uma limpeza no código. O motivo do erro apresentado ainda é desconhecido, mas com o código abaixo é possível compilar o [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/) de acordo com os parâmetros passados no [`ndk-build`](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/ndk-build.html).

zlib/Android.mk

---

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := libz
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -O3 -DUSE_MMAP
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(zlib_files)
ifneq ($(TARGET_BUILD_APPS),)
  LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := 9
else
  LOCAL_CXX_STL := none
endif
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDE_DIRS := $(LOCAL_PATH)
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
```

Para que não dê erro devido a falta do diretório `jni`, cria-se a pasta e o arquivo abaixo.

zlib/**`jni`**/**`Application.mk`** com o seguinte conteúdo:

---

```
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.9
APP_ABI := all
APP_PROJECT_PATH := $(shell pwd)
APP_BUILD_SCRIPT := $(APP_PROJECT_PATH)/Android.mk
```

Nota: Mude o valor de `NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION` de acordo com a versão suportada por seu compilador GCC no Android NDK. Aversão mais recente utiliza o valor `4.9`, para mais informações consulte a [documentação do Application.mk](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/application_mk.html).

Agora a biblioteca zlib pode ser compilada para múltiplas arquiteturas de acordo com o valor passado no `TARGET_ARCH_ABI` bastando abrir o console na pasta do zlib com o *botão direito do mouse*, depois selecionando a opção *Open in Console* e digitando o comando:

```
/run/media/root/linux/workspace/android-ndk-r11c/ndk-build TARGET_PLATFORM=android-14 TARGET_ARCH_ABI=x86 NDK_PROJECT_PATH=.
```

Lembrando que o `/run/media/root/linux/workspace/` refere-se a localização do seu Android NDK e o `TARGET_ARCH_ABI` a sua arquitetura, no exemplo acima foi usada a **`x86`**, verifique as [arquiteturas disponíveis](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html).

Outras informações sobre a compilação podem ser encontradas no site do [Android NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/index.html).